# Apache redirect non-ssl & www to ssl & non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I don't know how to do...

I need:

from
`http://example.com` or
`http://www.example.com` or
`https://www.example.com`
TO
`https://example.com`

and

from
`http://subdomain.example.com` or
`http://www.subdomain.example.com` or
`https://www.subdomain.example.com`
TO
`https://subdomain.example.com`

There is a lot of subdomains so I need a general decision...

Redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` (and from `http://subdomain.example.com` to `https://subdomain.example.com`) is working from hosting... without me.

and I did

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

so it's working for `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` (and for `https://www.subdomain.example.com` to `https://subdomain.example.com`)

**BUT somehow it's not working**
for
`http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` and `http://www.subdomain.example.com` to `https://subdomain.example.com` (www is still there)
So when I have http and www - redirect goes to https but keep www!
Than of course it do one more redirect, without www. But it's two redirects! I need remove www and add httpS in one redirect.

Comment: You probably forgot to enable to processing of your ".htaccess" style file in the configuration of your http host. Look out for the (probably missing) ``AllowOverride`` directive.

Comment: @arkascha And it should be All or None?

Comment: I said my .htaccess is worked for https. But http redirect to https with www and idk why

Comment: It should be "All", so that the configuration files get applied at all. And yes, that would be an explanation why that works for https, but not for http. Because both are completely separate virtual hosts having completely separate configuration.